# Number Blocks toy that changes colors according to how many blocks are connected

Tags: led, breadboard

Number Blocks is a British children's show that gets kids to enjoy learning numbers and simple arithmetic. I watch the show with my 4.5yo and it's really well done. One neat thing they do with the numbers is assign each a personality and a color scheme: 1-6 are ROYGBIV (-ish), 7 is a rainbow, 10 is white with a red outline, 20 is a lighter shade of orange than 2, etc. When they are teaching math, like 1+1=2, they show 2 red one-blocks combining to become 1 orange two-block.

[image: Number blocks 1-5]

I think it would be great to have a set of blocks that match the color-changing behavior of the TV show. A translucent block that can attach on any side to other blocks, where each block has an RGB LED inside (which would be diffused by the translucency). When a block is by itself, it would be red. When 2 blocks are connected, both blocks would be orange. When 3 blocks are connected, all the blocks would be yellow. When 7 blocks are connected, there'd be a ROYGBIV array. And so on, at least up to 10. The color scheme goes non-monochromatic after 10:

[image: Number Blocks 14]

When a set of blocks hasn't changed colors in a while, it would turn off to save battery (probably a watch battery in each block which I hope could be expected to last a long time).

I'm a software guy rather than an electrical engineer but I do some 3d printing as a hobby and I've been wondering how practical it would be for me to make a prototype. I've looked at [Cubelets](https://www.modrobotics.com/) but they are rather expensive and target a different demographic. (Also they don't have a 3 color LED block, just a flashlight block.)

My question for EE is what the most cost-effective electronics would look like on the inside? Could the "how many blocks are connected to me" kind of logic be done with a breadboard? Or would a microcontroller be necessary, greatly increasing the cost? I suspect 1-6, 8, and 10 (solid colors) should be possible without a microcontroller, but 7, 9, and 11-19 would be far trickier.

Comment: Microcontrollers "greatly increasing the cost?" - not really. A [micro for a task like this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/embedded-microcontrollers/685?s=N4IgjCBcoGwBwE4qgMZQC4CcCuBTANCAPZQDaIATAgMxyIiEVwCs1ALAOwPgAMHHCCtzB0KbIYTA9WzLpNHMYw0dSSSQAXUIAHdFBABlLAEsAdgHMQAX0YUecZCDSQseQiUjkJIatzbdmbiVCORAHLRBdfQBJU3Rcc1xMa0IAWiFoJwwcAmIyECQIqMgQaxtKfIBZYxRMIhQiOLqAG2akgAJNKyA) would be barely more than $1 or $2 each, and that's buying them in 1's and 2's not in 10's of thousands.

Comment: Having a microcontroller does not necessarily mean increased cost. Are you planning to make a set? or a million? If anything close to low scale, ease of development +flexibility means cheap - instead of a super specific hardware solution.

Comment: Shows what I know! I guess I was thinking an easily programmable microcontroller like Arduino/Pi. I'm not really familiar with cheaper ones. So I can get 10 programmable microcontrollers for less than $50?

Comment: This application doesn't demand too much computational power. An 8-bit microcontroller like the STM8S003 costs 30 cents a piece. (Yes, 30 cents) Despite being cheap, it is very capable (beats the ATmega328p on the Arduino Nano in most situations, except with less memory). I would absolutely recommend looking into STM8. On a side note, Pi is more of a microprocessor board rather than microcontroller. It is infinitely more powerful than what you need for this application.

Comment: Since it is a toy, mass producing them with a 3.3 cent (yes, about three cents) microcontroller will be faster and cheaper that a handful of logic chips that do the same thing. If it is a one-off toy for you only, and you design the hardware yourself, perhaps use one Arduino to program many separate MCUs?

Comment: Under $50: you can get 10 Arduino uno clones for under $30 or 10 nano clones for under $20, if you don't want to learn how to use "bare" microcontroller chips.

Comment: this may be of interest ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYhAGnsnO7w

Comment: THeir uCs start to get rather useful at about 10c each in modest volume.

Comment: Aliexpress Arduino example [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-arduino.html) - many more stores have them. || "Nano" has USB interface included and is simplest to program. ||"Mini" has no USB. You can connect a USB / RS232 converter for programming. Costs  slightly less per uC but less flexibility. || Pricing may/may-not include USB cable, free shipping, ... . Note that processor may vary and some are 3V3 only. 5V usually more desirable.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful comments. Going with the cheap Arduinos seems like the path of least resistance to a prototype (or one-off) for a software guy like me. Any recommendations on how to sense how many blocks are connected (not just adjacent)? One sensor on each face of the cube? One sensor per cube that is somehow distance limited so it only gets signals from the adjacent blocks? Can it be done contactlessly so the block's surface is solid plastic?

Comment: @MattChambers  There are a range of contactless methods BUT as you want to power the blocks and ideally don't want batteries in each block then having 2 or 3 contacts allows power transfer and signaling. Two wires can be used for both and 3 wires allows ground + power+bidirectional data. | You could also use inductive power transfer (IPT) between blocks (with signaling included) but it adds cost and complexity.   IPT is easier than you might expect . | Signaling only between battery equipped blocks could be capacitive, inductive (coil based) , optical , acoustic, magnetic (eg hall sensors)

Comment: Interesting idea with the battery blocks. That's the way Cubelets went, but it makes it a bit harder to play with: kids could only make as many "numbers" (i.e. a connected set of N blocks) as there are battery blocks, and they have to be careful that each "number" has one of those blocks. Would it still work if one "number" had 2+ blocks in it at the same time? Having a battery in each block would be simpler, but it would definitely need to be super power efficient and battery conserving because it would be a lot of batteries to replace.

Comment: The way I see it, each side of each block needs a 2-way signal. The "in" signal is the number of connected blocks from that side. The "out" signal is the number of connected blocks from all the other sides. In the simplest case, the block's uC would add those 2 numbers to determine the color it should be. The non-uniform color numbers would be trickier, particularly if the shape of the connected blocks is arbitrary (loops like a 2xN rectangle would need to be detected and counted properly, although I suppose kids could even make non-planar shapes 2x2x2 which don't occur on the TV show).

Comment: Love the idea! But I think the connector solution will be more expensive than the actual MCU. Maybe you could consider an analog determination of the number of cubes attached? Like if all blocks have a common line where each block adds a resistance to ground which are measured by each block simultaneously. Or a resistor in series with a current level which determines the number of blocks?